# Установка venv на Astra Linux

Tags: astra-linux, venv

Прошу помощи в установке пакета venv для создания виртуального окружения python на Astra Linux.

```
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ sudo apt-get update
Игн:1 https://download.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/1.7_x86-64/repository-main 1.7_x86-64 InRelease
Сущ:2 https://download.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/1.7_x86-64/repository-update 1.7_x86-64 InRelease
Сущ:3 https://download.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/1.7_x86-64/repository-main 1.7_x86-64 Release
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет python3-venv недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «python3-venv» не найден кандидат на установку
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ sudo apt-get install python3.7-venv
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет python3.7-venv недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «python3.7-venv» не найден кандидат на установку
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ python
python      python2     python2.7   python3     python3.7   python3.7m  python3m    
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ apt show python*-venv
Package: python3-venv
State: не реальный (виртуальный) пакет
Package: python3.7-venv
State: не реальный (виртуальный) пакет
N: Не найдено ни одного пакета
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ uname -a
Linux TAG-4786 5.4.0-162-generic #astra1+ci29-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 22 08:22:22 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ 
user@TAG-4786:~/enotdir$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: AstraLinux
Description:    Astra Linux 1.7 x86-64
Release:    1.7_x86-64
Codename:   1.7_x86-64
```

Comment: Добавьте в список источников `deb http://dl.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/1.7_x86-64/repository-base/ 1.7_x86-64 main`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло